# Is it possible to fail a maven build if sources are not up to date?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Quite simply I want to be able to run mvn install to compile and test my source code and then run a deploy at some point after running manual tests. What I want to be able to do is fail the deply if the source has been updated, i.e. if the compile artifacts are stale then fail the deploy rather than recompile.

Is this possible?

Comment: Start using a CI solution like jenkins. That's the point.

Comment: And the point of that response is? It does not answer the question or give any pointers to how to find an answer.

I am using a CI solution, Team City, but I want a triggered build that will deploy to a test environment, run automated tests and then allow some manual sanity tests before manually deploying the code through a manually triggered CI build step. I want this manually triggered build to fail if the source code has been updated, but vast experience has shown that actually you want to also be able to run these things manualy at times for whent here is an issue with the CI server

Comment: The problem is that you didn't wrote that in your questions so how could i know?. Apart from that just let run you CI server build a particular state of the software (from version control) deploy on the test system and that's it. Via this approach you prevent continious development. Why not deploying a particular state of the software (see your version control) and fix problems afterwards.